# SSMS Activity Monitor Expensive Query start time

Tags: sql-server

I keep seeing rows in "Recent Expensive Queries" for queries that have not been run for hours.

This confuses me when trying to figure what is snarling things up.

Is there a way to add start time column to view - or somehow filter old queries out?

Answer (score 1):

There are no such options!

However, you can create your own result set as shown in the following snippet.

Please, notice a couple of things.

First, you can change a period of time you are interested in by changing the first line of the snippet.

Second, the WHERE clause is applied on the last_execution_time column.

And, finally you can change the order if you are interested in expensive queries based on CPU or logical writes.

```
DECLARE @filterDateTime DATETIME = '2019-10-16 11:09:00.000'

SELECT TOP 10 SUBSTRING(qt.TEXT, (qs.statement_start_offset / 2) + 1, ((CASE qs.statement_end_offset
                                                                            WHEN-1
                                                                            THEN DATALENGTH(qt.TEXT)
                                                                            ELSE qs.statement_end_offset
                                                                        END - qs.statement_start_offset) / 2) + 1), 
              qs.execution_count, 
              qs.total_logical_reads, 
              qs.last_logical_reads, 
              qs.total_logical_writes, 
              qs.last_logical_writes, 
              qs.total_worker_time, 
              qs.last_worker_time, 
              qs.total_elapsed_time / 1000000 total_elapsed_time_in_S, 
              qs.last_elapsed_time / 1000000 last_elapsed_time_in_S, 
              qs.last_execution_time, 
              qp.query_plan
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs
     CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) qt
     CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(qs.plan_handle) qp
WHERE last_execution_time >= @filterDateTime
ORDER BY qs.total_logical_reads DESC; -- logical reads
-- ORDER BY qs.total_logical_writes DESC -- logical writes
-- ORDER BY qs.total_worker_time DESC -- CPU time
```

Comment: That is very useful! The total_worker_time is a very large number, probably because execution_count is high. If I divide total_worker_time by execution_count, does that give me the average cpu time for running the query once?

Comment: Also, is there anyway to add columns that shows what app or command line, initiated the query?

Comment: sys.dm_exec_query_stats returns  aggregate performance statistics for cached query plans in SQL Server. So, there is no details.

Comment: I didn't notice your first comment. The answer is yes!